# Building a new array from a filterered and keying it

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array that looks similar to this,

```
[
    [
        "Show/Hide",
        "P000",
        "MAX-CT05 FVM2-",
        "S",
        1532,
        -9.5929406005,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Open",
        null,
        "",
        null
    ],
    [
        "",
        "P000-000",
        "MAX-CT05 FVM2-",
        "S",
        22,
        -9.985,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Open",
        null,
        null,
        "P000"
    ],
    [
        "",
        "P000-002",
        "MAX-CT05 FVM2-",
        "S",
        250,
        -9.874,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Open",
        null,
        null,
        "P000"
    ],
    [
        "",
        "P000-003",
        "MAX-CT05 FVM2-",
        "S",
        1,
        -9.945,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Open",
        null,
        null,
        "P000"
    ],
    [
        "",
        "P000-001",
        "MAX-CT05 FVM2-",
        "S",
        1259,
        -9.53,
        45,
        null,
        null,
        "Open",
        null,
        null,
        "P000"
    ],
    [
        "Show/Hide",
        "P001",
        "MAX-CT07 TYM2-",
        "S",
        333,
        -1.8855675676,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Open",
        null,
        null,
        null
    ],
    [
        "",
        "P001-000",
        "MAX-CT07 TYM2-",
        "S",
        99,
        -1.865,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Open",
        null,
        "98.8mm JPM PB",
        "P001"
    ],
    [
        "",
        "P001-001",
        "MAX-CT07 TYM2-",
        "S",
        45,
        -1.866,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Open",
        null,
        null,
        "P001"
    ],
    [
        "",
        "P001-002",
        "MAX-CT07 TYM2-",
        "S",
        189,
        -1.901,
        7,
        null,
        -1.901,
        "Open",
        null,
        null,
        "P001"
    ]
    
]
```

I have another array that looks like this,

```
[
    {
        "header": true
    },
    {
        "pk": "P000",
        "nest": 0
    },
    {
        "pk": "P000-000",
        "nest": 1
    },
    {
        "pk": "P000-002",
        "nest": 1
    },
    {
        "pk": "P000-003",
        "nest": 1
    },
    {
        "pk": "P000-001",
        "nest": 1
    },
    {
        "pk": "P001",
        "nest": 0
    },
    {
        "pk": "P001-000",
        "nest": 1
    },
    {
        "pk": "P001-001",
        "nest": 1
    },
    {
        "pk": "P001-002",
        "nest": 1
    }
]
```

This array basically outlines parent child structure, if the `nest` value is zero then then the array at the index in the other array is parent, if the `nest` value is `1` then the array at that index is a child, what I wanting to do is loop over the second array and create a new array of grouped children indexed by their parents index, something like,

```
[
    0: [
        [
        "",
        "P000-000",
        "MAX-CT05 FVM2-",
        "S",
        22,
        -9.985,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Open",
        null,
        null,
        "P000"
    ],
    [
        "",
        "P000-002",
        "MAX-CT05 FVM2-",
        "S",
        250,
        -9.874,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Open",
        null,
        null,
        "P000"
    ],
    [
        "",
        "P000-003",
        "MAX-CT05 FVM2-",
        "S",
        1,
        -9.945,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Open",
        null,
        null,
        "P000"
    ],
    [
        "",
        "P000-001",
        "MAX-CT05 FVM2-",
        "S",
        1259,
        -9.53,
        45,
        null,
        null,
        "Open",
        null,
        null,
        "P000"
    ]
    ],
    1: [
       [
        "",
        "P001-000",
        "MAX-CT07 TYM2-",
        "S",
        99,
        -1.865,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Open",
        null,
        "98.8mm JPM PB",
        "P001"
    ],
    [
        "",
        "P001-001",
        "MAX-CT07 TYM2-",
        "S",
        45,
        -1.866,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Open",
        null,
        null,
        "P001"
    ],
    [
        "",
        "P001-002",
        "MAX-CT07 TYM2-",
        "S",
        189,
        -1.901,
        7,
        null,
        -1.901,
        "Open",
        null,
        null,
        "P001"
    ]
  ]
]
```

I realise this above is not a valid format I don't think, currently this is what my attempt looks like,

```
let parentIndex = -1;
this.current.row_meta_data.filter((row: any, index: number) => {
  if(!row.header) {
    if(row.nest == 0) {
      this.current.childRows[`parent_${index}]`] = [];
      parentIndex = index;
    }
    debugger;
    if(row.nest == 1) {
      this.current.childRows[`parent_${index}`].push({
        values: this.current.values[index],
        cell_styles: this.current.cell_styles[index],
        formatted_values: this.current.formatted_values[index],
        unique_styles: this.current.unique_styles[index]
      });
    }
  }
});
```

But I am getting an error

> Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'parent_1]')

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure of the variables that you have
but can you add `this.current.childRows` to both if conditions?
for example:

```
if (row.nest == 0 && this.current.childRows)
```

and also same for the second condition

Comment: this.current.childRows is the array I am trying to push into.

Comment: yes, the error says this array doesn't exist in the second loop "index of 1" so you can add the array variable to the if condition